# Is it possible to run H2O models in Android?

Tags: java, android, h2o

I've trained a model in [H2O](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3) and save it as MOJO following [this tutorial](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/mojo-quickstart.html).

Then, I've created a new Android app including the saved model and `h2o-genmodel.jar`. Gradle build runs successfully, but when I try to run it on the Android phone I get the following error:

```
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed: INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS
Installation failed due to: 'null'
```

My guess is that the `jar` file has been generated only for x86 and not arm chips, but I'd like to know if it's possible at all to run it on Android.

Comment: They also have Gradle dependencies of their artifacts. try using those

Comment: I would expect the xgboost model type to not work without substantial dev effort since it uses a compiled binary wrapped in a jar file for inferencing.  But most h2o-3 model types produce a MOJO that works with pure java inferencing.  So I’d say there is a good shot it would work.  (As well as any other java code out there.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it worked by using a Gradle dependency instead of loading jar file.

```
implementation 'ai.h2o:h2o-genmodel:3.28.0.3'
```

Thank you @hfarhanahmed and @TomKraljevic for your help.